# Bing Maps v8 and strange work of instanceof

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Load map:

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    ...
});
```

And it works fine (visually). But:

```
console.log(map instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Map);  // false
```

Whaaat?! :) How can I check it? Is it a bug or my mistake?

You can try example in Bing Dev Center sandbox:

http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#loadMapAsync+JS

Thanks

Comment: Can you check what `console.dir(Object.getPrototypeoOf(map))` logs?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Bing Apps dev page, if you edit out the `new` it still works, and logging `map.constructor` just prints `function n()`. So it appears Microsoft has not been entirely accurate as to what the code does at the moment - which is to act as an object factory.

Microsoft *may* be reserving the right to make `Maps.Map` an object constructor in the future. At the moment `instanceof` returning `false` is correct.

Comment: This is by design. The Map object is a wrapper around another class. V8 actually has a whole other set of code syntax which is internal to microsoft and was wrapped to make it backwards compatible with V7

Comment: @rbrundritt thanks. Do you know if the object created by `new` is used? I  am **not** suggesting  leaving the `new` keyword out in case it is used for non-obvious reasons or if Microsoft requires it in the future.

Comment: Funny enough, I never knew that the map would load without the new keyword. Past versions of Bing Maps would have thrown an error. I would recommend leaving it in as it will be less likely to break since this is how it is documented.